# Placing application configuration in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm running a grails application on tomcat7 server. I have some application properties stored in 'application-config.groovy' file, which is read via

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:application-config.groovy"]
```

line in Config.groovy. Where in tomcat folder should I put properties file so that application can read it this way.

I've been running the app on glassfish server before, and this config was placed in domains/appname/config folder.

UPD: I cannot use grails-app/conf folder since this way config will be built in the war and I need to configure app from the outside to be able to run several environments with one war. I also cannot specify full paths to config files because I cannot rely on servers directory structure.

The best would be to find a directory in tomcat where application may store configs. Somebody knows this directory?

Comment: It might be the `grails-app/conf` but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define exact path where config is stored. Consider example:

```
app.config.dir = "/etc/yourapp/config/" // replace with directory with your application's config
grails.config.locations = ["file:${app.config.dir}application-config.groovy"]
```

For more info take a look in [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#configExternalized).

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation found [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized), you should specify either classpath or the full path.

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                            "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

I didn't see where it picks up from by default. I'd try @CeilingGecko's recommendation of `grails-app/conf`.

Comment: I do not know where the tomcat's classpath is. I tried to put configfile into tomcat/lib folder, but it was not read from there.

Comment: I think it's the classpath of your app. So put it under `src/java/<appname>-config.properties` or wherever is best.